# Jquery Datatable Loses Horizontal Scroll Bar on Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, datatable

I have an intriguing problem that I thought I resolved with a janky solution, but I only half solved it. I'm using Datatables for Jquery and I'm loading in data from a database to populate the table.

I should note that been developing using Firefox.

Additionally, I have a horizontal scroll bar and the first five columns are fixed. This poses a problem because before all of the data is loaded, the datatable puts in a horizontal scroll bar. Some of the data loaded after the scroll bar is initialized is longer in length and thus makes the column widths larger.

To resolve this, I just call a resize

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
},2000);
</script>
```

What happens here is I see the page load, the table is initially messed up, but after a brief delay (a little less that 2 seconds as it should be because of the time I've given to the timeout), the table fixes itself because of the window resize.

I thought the problem was fixed, until I began testing in Chrome. The table will be initially messed up, just as it is in Firefox, but once the resize is called, the table extends horizontally, loses the horizontal scroll bar, and the chrome window gets one. That's not ideal because the point of the scroll bar is to keep the table within the width of the screen size.

To contain the width of the table, I use the following CSS:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper{
    width: 96vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I define the table like so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );

new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(example,{
    leftColumns:5
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can mimic the load time on jsfiddle. If you can, I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: So I've narrowed the problem down to different versions of Chromium. I'm currently using 43.0.23571.130 and it doesn't work, but it does work in 43.0.23571.81. Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to force the `width` of the `datatables_scrollBody` to `100%` in order to maintain the horizontal bar visible.

```
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```